# Override ComboBox Styles?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a `Style` in `Window.Resources` applied to all the `ComboBox` in the application. However, I have come across a situation where I need the styles in the `Window.Resources` applied to the `ComboBox`, but I need to disable one feature I have specifically set in the styles.

I want to be able to enter text into one `ComboBox` in the application.
Being that the `ComboBox` text editable part is actually a `TextBox` I set disabled the `TextBox` altogether: This style is specifically for the `ComboBox` style I have,

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            <....More setters etc
```

I have also set in the `ComboBox` styles `IsEditable` to false. I had to apply this style to both the `TextBox` part of the `ComboBox` to the style work correctly. I have also included the code pointing to the static resource to `x:Key="ComboBoxTextBoxStyle"` shown above:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False" />
            <...More setter's
               <Setter.Value>
                   <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxStyle}" 
                         <...More styles applied here
```

So now I have a `ComboBox` that I want to be able to enter text into, so I set the XAML to this,

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Cmb" IsEditable="True" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static viewModels:ShiftManagerViewModel.MyBindingList}}"
  SelectedItem="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=MySeletcProperty}" />
```

But, the `ComboBox` is not able to be able to enter text even though I have set the actuall `ComboBox` to `IsEditable="True"`.

### How do I override the styles to allow this one `ComboBox` enter text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create a new Style which will inherit from that Style that already exists and apply it to that particular combox box, style would be like:

A better apporach is that your TextBox element in  Style Template for ComboBox `IsEnabled` property should have binding to ComboBox `IsEditable` property :

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Setter Property="IsEnabled" 
          Value="{Binding Path=IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" />
```

and then in xaml consuming side you can specify this style :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Cmb" IsEditable="True"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static viewModels:ShiftManagerViewModel.MyBindingList}}"
  SelectedItem="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=MySeletcProperty}" />
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for that, that was really kicking my butt.